# Convert input word into vector matrix

Tags: matrix, string-manipulation, vector

I wold like some help of converting an input (word or number or mix) into a single row vector, such as the following:

If input is ">DAVID123<" I want it to be as {>,D,A,V,I,D,1,2,3,<}

where all letters considered as unknown variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ToExpression[Select[Characters[">DAVID123<" ],StringMatchQ[#,LetterCharacter]&]]
```

which will give you a vector of

```
{D,A,V,I,D}
```

as symbols or variables, but `C` and `D` and `E` and `I` and `K` have predefined meaning inside of Mathematica and may cause you grief.

Comment: what about the < and > can I convert them into 0 ? Also where are the numbers {1,2,3} ?

Comment: This  `ToExpression[Characters[StringReplace[">DAVID123<",PunctuationCharacter:>"0"]]]` gives you `{0,D,A,V,I,D,1,2,3,0}